# Posibility placing two outlook web addins in one group

Tags: office365, office-js

Is it generally possible to place two seperate outlook web addins in the same group by specifying the same groupd id for the controls in the addin?

Comment: Who's stop you to try? ;) Change your existing add-in manifest Id, change the groups information as you need and sore it as copy; deploy second manifest, observe result.

Comment: Do you mean two add-ins with different manifests and extension ids?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of two commands of the same add-in in the same group. Each of these buttons can open a different taskpane. There is no way today to make two add-ins with two different manifests appear in the same group.

`<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
   <OfficeTab id="msgComposeTab">
     <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
       <Label resid="groupLabel" />
         <!-- Task pane button -->
         <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
           <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
           <Supertip>
             <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
             <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
           </Supertip>
           <Icon>
             <bt:Image size="16" resid="taskpanecommand-icon" />
             <bt:Image size="32" resid="taskpanecommand-icon" />
             <bt:Image size="80" resid="taskpanecommand-icon" />
           </Icon>
           <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
             <SourceLocation resid="composeTaskPaneUrl" />
           </Action>
         </Control>
         <!-- Task pane button -->
         <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeOpenPaneButton">
           <Label resid="paneComposeButtonLabel" />
           <Supertip>
             <Title resid="paneComposeSuperTipTitle" />
             <Description resid="paneComposeSuperTipDescription" />
           </Supertip>
           <Icon>
             <bt:Image size="16" resid="taskpanecommand-icon" />
             <bt:Image size="32" resid="taskpanecommand-icon" />
             <bt:Image size="80" resid="taskpanecommand-icon" />
           </Icon>
           <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
             <SourceLocation resid="composeTaskPaneUrl" />
           </Action>
         </Control>
       </Group>
     </OfficeTab>
   </ExtensionPoint>`